# Number of the same elements in a row - ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

A have simple array with a strings.
I need to know if there exist 10 elements in a row which contain "ffff" string. I found solution like: `each_with_index` then add a few counters(`if string.exist?` increment counter, on the next cycle - compare counter: increment if string exist again OR reset the counter if not), but that looks ugly. Probably there is some elegant solution?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide sample inputs and outputs, as well as the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write something like:

```
my_array.each_cons(10).any?{|subarray| subarray.all?{|item| item['ffff']}}
```

Comment: `each_cons` returns a list of subarrays that have overlapping elements. Which will make uneccessary computation, consult it in the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

Comment: Iterates the given block for each array of consecutive <n> elements. If no block is given, returns an enumerator. No list is returned unless you ask it to convent the enumerator to a list. If you would use any other enumerable function like each slice it would not answer the question properly.

Comment: It says "10 elements in a row" so i assumed they must be all next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, different than the one proposed by [hirolau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28435727/676788), which is a little more verbose, but may be with better performance.

```
# a recursive method which return true or false
def consecutive(array, pattern, count)
   return false if array.empty?
   # Filter out the first elements not matching the pattern
   filtered = array.drop_while{|a| !a[pattern] }
   # Take the first elements matching the pattern from the filtered array
   cons = filtered.take_while{ |a| a[pattern] }
   if(cons.count >= count)
     true
   else
     # this time filter out the first elements matching the pattern
     # because their number does not equal the desired count
     filtered = filtered.drop_while{ |a| a[pattern] }
     consecutive(filtered, pattern, count)
   end
end

array = ["ffff",
         "ffff",
         "ffff",
         "er",
         "er",
         "ffff",
         "ffff",
         "er",
         "reffff",
         "bffff",
         "fffftr",
         "ffffm",
         "ffff",
         "ffff",
         "ffff",
         "ffff",
         "ffff",
         "ffffcf"]

puts consecutive(array, /f{4}/, 10)
```

Comment: This does not care if the elements appear in a row or not, and does not work if there are not exactly 10.

Comment: @hirolau yes you're right, I didn't get the question right.